# How to generate an apk file using ANT?

Tags: java, android, ant

When i run as java application, i got this error. i included build.xml to build and generating apk file from java application.

[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource anttasks.properties. It could not be found.
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. It could not be found.

-check-env:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Android_workspace\apktest\build.xml:246: Problem: failed to create task or type checkenv
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

Total time: 0 seconds

Comment: can you post build.xml ?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the new build system?!

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here {[How to generate apk file programmatically through java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512088/how-to-generate-apk-file-programmatically-through-java-code/19517909#19517909)}

i think your problem here that you need to update the build.xml file by running this command:

```
android update project --name <project_name> --target <target_ID> --path <path_to_your_project>
```

Comment: Can you please explain me that where to use this above **Android update project command** and which kit should i use?. Is it JDK or SDK (eclipse)?.

Comment: You will need to run the above command in CMD, you will need to use eclipse IDE and use the steps in the link above

Comment: If i run **android update project -p . -t 3** command in command prompt it is showing me an error(Error: C:\workspace\javatest is not a valid project (AndroidManifest.xml not found). Where javatest is my Android project name. tell me how to solve this error.