# CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, process

I am writing a program in java which would execute winrar and unzip a jar file for me placed in `h:\myjar.jar` into the folder `h:\new`. My java code goes something like this

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = null;

        try {
            File dir = new File("C:/Program Files/WinRAR");
            p = r.exec("winrar x h:\\myjar.jar *.* h:\\new", null, dir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this, I am getting this error

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "winrar" (in directory "C:\Program Files\WinRAR"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:16)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Can anyone tell me why am I encountering such a problem. What is the change I need to incorporate in code so that it works?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Assuming that `winrar.exe` is in the `PATH`, then `Runtime.exec` is capable of finding it, if it is not, you will need to supply the fully qualified path to it, for example, assuming `winrar.exe` is installed in `C:/Program Files/WinRAR` you would need to use something like...

```
p=r.exec("C:/Program Files/WinRAR/winrar x h:\\myjar.jar *.* h:\\new");
```

Personally, I would recommend that you use `ProcessBuilder` as it has some additional configuration abilities amongst other things.  Where possible, you should also separate your command and parameters into separate `String` elements, it deals with things like spaces much better then a single `String` variable, for example...

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
    "C:/Program Files/WinRAR/winrar",
    "x",
    "myjar.jar",
    "*.*",
    "new");
pb.directory(new File("H:/"));
pb. redirectErrorStream(true);

Process p = pb.start();
```

Don't forget to read the contents of the `InputStream` from the process, as failing to do so may stall the process

Comment: my case just i put path to bin for that exe in my system variables in windows

Comment: I ran python code with the full path to python.exe directory. Thank you

Answer (score 29):

I used ProcessBuilder but had the same issue. The issue was with using command as one String line (like I would type it in cmd) instead of String array. In example from above. If I ran

```
ProcessBuilder pb = 
   new ProcessBuilder("C:/Program Files/WinRAR/winrar x myjar.jar *.* new");
pb.directory(new File("H:/"));
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process p = pb.start();
```

I got an error. But if I ran

```
ProcessBuilder pb = 
   new ProcessBuilder("C:/Program Files/WinRAR/winrar", "x", "myjar.jar", "*.*", "new");
pb.directory(new File("H:/"));
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process p = pb.start();
```

everything was OK.

Comment: This fixed it for me.  The critical thing was the `pb.directory(...)` statement.  As others mentioned below, once you do that, you can just have the name of the exe as the first command argument.  I did also have to use the cmd /c like so  

`List<String> params = Arrays.asList("cmd", "/c", "quack1.exe", "inputfile.txt", "param1", "param2", "A");
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(params);
   pb.directory(new File("C:/dev/test"));
   Process pr = (pb).start();`

Answer (score 16):

The `dir` you specified is a working directory of running process - it doesn't help to find executable. Use `cmd /c winrar ...` to run process looking for executable in **PATH** or try to use *absolute* path to *winrar*.

Comment: Can u please tell me the command for knowing the absolute path..?

Comment: p = rt.exec(new String[] {"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\winrar.exe", "x", "h:\\myjar.jar", "*.*", "h:\\new" }
            null, 
            dir);...i still get the same error.

Comment: what if you perform `rt.exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c", "winrar.exe x h:\\myjar.jar . h:\\new"}, null, dir)` ?

Answer (score 3):

The complete first argument of `exec` is being interpreted as the executable. Use

```
p = rt.exec(new String[] {"winrar.exe", "x", "h:\\myjar.jar", "*.*", "h:\\new" }
            null, 
            dir);
```

Comment: Is `winrar.exe` on your PATH?

Comment: I have just installed winrar...i didn't set the environment path for winrar

Comment: It needs to be on the PATH otherwise you will have to specify the full path along with the executable

Answer (score 2):

My recomendation is to keep the `getRuntime().exec` because `exec` uses the `ProcessBuilder`.

Try

```
 p=r.exec(new String[] {"winrar", "x", "h:\\myjar.jar", "*.*", "h:\\new"}, null, dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either way worked for me: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...) or using the ProcessBuilder. Still for some calls it still failed with the same error as stated in the original question: "CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified". On closer inspection, that was because I was executing a command file that made use of current directory references (%~dp0). Apparently they did not work, even when calling the command from the same directory. Using absolute paths solved the problem.