# JAVA: Runtime.getRuntime().exec() The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java

I have an exe file: "TVRRun.exe" that is located in the directory: "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeleVantage\Client\Reporter".

I'm trying to run that exe file from java code:

```
public static void runTVRRun() throws IOException {
    String path = System.getenv("programfiles(x86)") + "\\TeleVantage\\Client\\Reporter\\";
    String[] command = {"TVRRun.exe", "-S", templatePath, "-S", tmpReportPath};
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, new File(path));
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: 
Cannot run program "TVRRun.exe" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeleVantage\Client\Reporter"): 
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've tried all variations of the exec function, and also ProcessBuilder, but the same error appears.

Comment: check the env variable I think you put space between `Files (x86)`

Comment: That's not the problem. if I copy the location from the error, the file runs. I even created a bat file that runs the exe file. by running the bat file manually, it runs, running the bat from java, the bat runs, but the exe doesn't.

Comment: where is the name of the file in path

Comment: The file is: TVRRun.exe

Comment: no I am saying you are creating instace of File without specifying the name of the file you only specified path so try with `String path = System.getenv("programfiles(x86)") + "\\TeleVantage\\Client\\Reporter\\TVRRun.exe";`

Comment: I've tried that too, same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621838/createprocess-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified this solves it