# Runtime.getRuntime().exec -> Cannot run program CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, windows, command-line, runtime, exec

I'm developing a command line java app that must run a program called `gradlew.bat assembleRelease` inside this directory: `this.workDir+"/Project/CapAndroid"`

So i did this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gradlew.bat assembleRelease", null , new File(this.workDir+"/Project/CapAndroid"));
```

The file is in that directory 100% sure and it works perfect in linux but did not work on Windows! I got this error:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gradlew.bat" (in directory
>   "C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\generators\And\jobs\2247994\Project\CapAndroid"):
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I think windows has a problem to know that the command passed in the first parameter of exec() method must be executed in the directory passed in the last parameter. Linux works perfect, also OS X too, the problem is only in Windows

Thanks a lot

Comment: The command on linux and MacOS X is `gradlew.bat`?

Comment: no, its simply gradlew without bat, i rename it, it is a constant

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621838/createprocess-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified

Comment: remove your possible duplicate comment, that error was for a space in the absolute path

Comment: Seems like your are specifying a system path in your program, check that path as per the error, your program is not able to find that path. :)

Comment: what you mean? that path is correct, if i manually do cd path in the console it enters the path and then i can run the program

Answer (score 12):

Well, i finally solved it adding `cmd /c` before the name of the .bat file, now it works perfectly:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c gradlew.bat assembleRelease", null , new File(this.workDir+"/Project/CapAndroid"));
```

i hope this will help someone in the future

Comment: Yes, it helped me today... !!

Comment: Great thing, thanks a lot, I will automatize all my setup processes for the local environment this year ;)