# How to get result of console command from java code?

Tags: java

I have following code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("dir"); // or cat in linux
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
String result = IOUtils.toString(p.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(result);
```

It throws

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dir": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
```

I understand that I can write something like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("test.bat");
```

and inside `test.bat` you can write

```
dir
```

But it returns:

```
D:\nsd-rest>dir
 Volume in drive D is SECOND
 Volume Serial Number is CE52-8896

 Directory of D:\nsd-rest

03/24/17  15:53    <DIR>          .
03/24/17  15:53    <DIR>          ..
03/24/17  12:00               249 .gitignore
03/24/17  16:54    <DIR>          .idea
03/24/17  15:01    <DIR>          .mvn
03/24/17  12:00             7,058 mvnw
03/24/17  12:00             5,006 mvnw.cmd
03/24/17  15:53             6,265 nsd-rest.iml
03/24/17  15:52             1,993 pom.xml
03/24/17  15:01    <DIR>          src
03/24/17  15:19    <DIR>          target
03/24/17  16:52                 3 test.bat
               6 File(s)         20,574 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  587,412,844,544 bytes free
```

Row

```
D:\nsd-rest>dir
```

is redundant.

When I invoke bat file I feel that I do something incorrect.

Can you provide correct solution?

**P.S.** instead of `dir` can be any executable file.

Comment: Just a thought, Java may not have access to the same environment variables as your command prompt. (e.g. %PATH%)

Comment: @CraigR8806 Is there way to add dir to path ?

Comment: First argument in commands for process builder is treated as executable file, from what I can see, there's no exception to that rule. What you actually want is execute command line process with passing "dir" as first argument to that process.

Comment: [This may help] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621838/createprocess-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

Comment: `waitFor()` returns after the process has *finished.*  Call it *after* you are done reading from the InputStream.

Comment: **String result = IOUtils.toString(p.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        p.waitFor();**  @VGR - is it correct ?

Comment: Yes.  Although, you really should check the value returned by p.waitFor().  If it’s not zero, the external command failed.  How you choose to do that is up to you, but your program should not act like the process succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `dir` executable actually - e.g. you can't find `dir.exe` anywhere on windows. This is pseudo-command which exist in `cmd.exe` executable context only.

If you want to get "dir" output - you can simply run `cmd.exe /c dir`

Also there's bug in your program:

```
p.waitFor();
String result = IOUtils.toString(p.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
```

If program output is large enough and wouldn't fit into output buffer, `p.waitFor()` would never end - because buffer is overflown and nobody is reading it. I'd suggest swap these lines(or even better - read couple articles about interprocess IO, that's related to everything not to java world only).

Comment: That, of course, means it will only work on Windows systems.

Comment: I'd never run `dir` directly, but rather iterate through File.list() or something similar but that wasn't the original question.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe /c dir": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Did you pass argument via process builder arguments? Since files in windows can have space in it's name `new ProcessBuilder("cmd /c dir")` wouldn't work.

Comment: Try `new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","dir")`

Comment: It actually supposed to be `new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "dir")`

Comment: @M. Prokhorov Can you explain menaing **"/c"** parameter ?

Comment: cmd /? is your best friend.