# JButton executing an exe file in directory

Tags: java, swing, process, jbutton

let's say I have a JButton called "Play", and when I click this, it should launch C:/play.exe. How do I manage to do this? I'd love to see an example.

Comment: If you are looking to run `CMD` comands then Read [Run cmd commands through java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464111/run-cmd-commands-through-java)

Comment: this forum is about [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), your effort, lets say can be accepted on another forums, otherwise read official Oracle tutorial, there is everything with excelent details

Comment: Look up examples for ProcessBuilder and read the docs...

Comment: @mKorbel What do you mean about my effort? I asked a precise question, isn't that what his website it about? I've coded the entire program, and now I need to make my Jbutton execute the downloaded .exe file that it downloaded. But I'm not sure how to do this, that's why I asked.

Comment: @user2966573 mr korbel means that you have to show up some code what you have tried to do.

Comment: something that exactly to identify how did you so far ..., this is question for google, can returns then same sugestions

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the javadoc for [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) which contains an example of how to create a process on the underlying system.

From there it's a simple matter of hooking it up to the button's [ActionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method. See this example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends JFrame {
   public Main() throws HeadlessException {
     setSize(200, 200);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

     JLabel label = new JLabel("Click here: ");
     JButton button = new JButton();

     button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
           Process process = null;
           System.exit(0);
           try {
               process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/play.exe");
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

        }
     });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Main().setVisible(true);
  }
}
```