# How I can use CMD Command in Java program?

Tags: java, cmd

I want to use cmd Commands in java program,

Want to crope all images in folder, I downlaoded ImageMagick, and using cmd commands Its working 1 image,

```
cd C:\Users\Robert\Java-workspace\Crop_test\Crop_test1
cd  convert -crop 312x312+0-10 image1.jpg new_image1.jpg
```

But, I want to use this in Java so, I can crop all images in folder by program, Here is my java program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.omg.CORBA.portable.OutputStream;

 public class test1 {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "C:\\Users\\Robert\\Java-workspace\\Crop_test\\Crop_test1\\", "convert -crop 312x312+0-10 image1.jpg new_image1.jpg"); 
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that `"convert -crop 312x312+0-10 image1.jpg new_image1.jpg"` should be separated parameters. Also it seems that directory should not be part of command. Maybe add it later using `pb.directory(new File("put path here"))`

Comment: Like, ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "convert", "-crop 312x312+0-10", "image1.jpg","new_image1.jpg"); 
     pb.directory(new File("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Java-workspace\\Crop_test\\Crop_test1\\")); Please help me!! thanks

Comment: Something like that. Does it work? If not then maybe try to print error stream of `p` Process and share what error you get.

Comment: I tried but not working, Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15464111/

Comment: `import java.io.OutputStream;` was originally intended (though not used here).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help guys found the solution!!

Answer (score 2):

Although you are asking how to use CMD and this was addressed on other answers I think that the best solution (considering your explanation of your implementation) would be to use a ImageMagick wrapper for Java as you can see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#java).

Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much for your help guys found the solution!!

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke CMD commands as follows in Java;

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(your_command);
```

Best thing for you to do is to creat a batch file with the commands you need to run and then invoke your batch file using the following command;

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start D:\\test.bat");
```

because you cannot do any change directory commands using the Runtime class. Please try this option and let me know if you face any other issues.

Comment: You can also use ProcessBuilder, and the questioner already knows this.  This answer does not help at all.

Comment: Yes you can, but why add complexity when you can achieve the same with minimal code?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I tried that same thing!!Please help me thanks!!

Comment: @dinukadev : ProcessBuilder internally does the same thing... It provides an extra layer of abstraction, that's all... And an extra layer of abstraction means extra safety and simpler usage...

Comment: byt using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Java-workspace\\R_Java_Map\\Map_Image\\", "convert -crop 312x312+0-10 image1.jpg new_image1.jpg"); Like This?? Please help me!! Thanks

Comment: @user3187463 i have edited my answer. Please check this option.

Comment: Thank for your answer but, I want to crop all images in folder, not only one image soo.. is there anyway, I can use that command in cmd and than create bat file use this line.. that you so much for your solution.. or I just need to enter cd line in bat file and from java i can enter convert line?? Please help me!! Thanks!!

Comment: can you try as follows..  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C cd \"C:\\Users\\Robert\\Java-workspace\\R_Java_Map\\Map_Image\" && convert -crop 312x312+0-10 image1.jpg new_image1.jpg");

Comment: I tried but same thing, it didn't convert image.. please help me!! Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help guys found the solution!!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try (both of which are untested):

1. Put a `cd` in the command line and use `&&` to run both commands in one line.

   ```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;

   import org.omg.CORBA.portable.OutputStream;

    public class test1 {
       public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

           ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cd C:\\Users\\Robert\\Java-workspace\\Crop_test\\Crop_test1\\ && convert -crop 312x312+0-10 image1.jpg new_image1.jpg"); 
           pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
           Process p = pb.start();
           p.waitFor();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Change the directory that the `ProcessBuilder` starts in:

   ```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;

   import org.omg.CORBA.portable.OutputStream;

    public class test1 {
       public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

           ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "convert -crop 312x312+0-10 image1.jpg new_image1.jpg");
           pb.directory(new File("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Java-workspace\\Crop_test\\Crop_test1\\"));
           pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
           Process p = pb.start();
           p.waitFor();
       }
   }
   ```

Incidentally, are you sure you want to import `org.omg.CORBA.portable.OutputStream`?  Did you mean `java.io.OutputStream` instead?

**EDIT**: if things still aren't working, then the next step is to see whether the problem is that  `convert` isn't being found.  Let's just run `convert` on its own without any arguments and see if it spits out its usage message to standard output.  Run the following:

```
public class test1 {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "convert");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();
        StreamGobbler g = new StreamGobbler(p.getInputStream(), "OUT");
        g.start();
        p.waitFor();
    }
}
```

Use the [StreamGobbler class here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2).  Does this print out `convert`'s usage method, with each line prefixed with `OUT>`?

Comment: ohh ya java.io.OutputStream yap,Thanks you so much for your help, I tried, still not working!!Please help me, Thanks!!

Comment: @user3187463 `not working` is not good explanation of problem. What do you mean by that? Do you get any errors? Does it work different that you expected? Does it not affect anything?

Comment: I am sorry, I tried your code, its not giving me any error, but, I check in folder, it didn't convert or create new image.. Please help me!! thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'?  Which approaches did you try, and what was the outcome?  Were there any error messages?   Did the code hang?  Have you tried connecting a [StreamGobbler](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2) to the output stream?  Is the return code returned by `waitFor` zero or not?

Comment: I tried first one, It didn't give me any error, nothing print out, I checked folder old image is in folder but, it didn't create new image in that folder, Please help me!! Thanks in advanced!!

Comment: @user3187463: you haven't answered all of my questions.  What was the exit code returned by `waitFor()`?  What output do you get if you use a StreamGobbler, as previously linked to?  Also, please note that I've added the line `pb.redirectErrorStream(true);` to both code blocks above.  That redirects standard error into standard output, so that you don't have to read from standard error and standard output separately.

Comment: @user3187463: the next thing to try is to see if you can run `convert` on its own without any arguments and without setting the directory.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I did try it, but.. please help me!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: But...  but...  what?  I went to the effort of writing out some code that I thought might help determine where the problem is, and all you can say is 'I did try it, but...', and leave me guessing at what actually happened.  **By not answering the questions I'm asking you you are making it very difficult to help you.**

Comment: Thank you so much for your help guys found the solution!!