# Run cmd command without creating a .bat file

Tags: java, cmd

is there a way to execute a cmd command like "move FolderA FolderB" without creating a .bat file and start it? 
It would be nice if it would work without creating files on HDD.

Comment: Why is Java Tagged in this question ?

Comment: @Sharpedge I assume they want to do it from a Java program; though I only inferred it from the tag, so I could be wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run cmd commands through java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464111/run-cmd-commands-through-java)

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","move","dirA/a.txt","dirB"});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Process process = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe",
                       "/c","move","dirA/a.txt","dirB").start();
```

`ProcessBuilder` is preferred to `Runtime.exec()` since Java 1.5, according to JavaDoc.

Be sure to read the `Process` Javadoc to understand how to read from and write to processes.

Shelling out for commands like `move` is bad practice, because it's neither portable nor secure. Work with `File` classes instead. But sometimes you have to shell out to interact with more esoteric external programs.

Comment: I sadly have to shell out and make the function "windows-only", because java let windows do the file-moving-process. only single cmd commands move files in a sorted order.

Comment: There is definitely nothing you can do with 'move' that you can't do with pure Java.

Comment: That is not right. When java or apache commons do the moving, the process begins e.g. at "e.txt" instead of "a.txt", if you 26 files, a.txt....z.txt

Comment: I suggest you put your java move code into a new question and ask why it's skipping a-d. There will be a fault in your code.

Comment: Hi, I think I found the problem. After moving a file, java needs to wait 0.1 seconds. Than the moving is in a sorted order.