# How to Invoke a single test suite multiple times in testng

Tags: java, testng

I have a requirement where in I need to execute all the suites in the testng.xml file for a number of times say 5.I know how to run a single test case multiple times by using invocationcount attribute but I don't have any idea how to run a suite multiple times.Any help will be appreciated a lot

Comment: Extremely vague question. What is this 'suite'? what kind of program is it? is it sqlplus or java? is it something you run on a linux system? why is ssh tagged?

Comment: Well how are you running the testcases now ? Ant ?

Comment: not through ant.I am using testng.xml file

Comment: how do you run the test ?

Comment: I am running from command line

Comment: Then you can write a script a batch file which will run the testng.xml once , do things you want to do in between and then again run the same testng.xml again . That should achieve what you wnat to do

Answer (score 1):

Then you can write a script a batch file which will run the testng.xml once , do things you want to do in between and then again run the same testng.xml again . That should achieve what you wnat to do

Comment: Till now I am doing the same thing.I am running the testng.xml file from the command line(unix terminal) by putting it in a .sh file.I have a separate .sh file which invokes the first file in a for loop.But I don't want it to be like this.It should be done programatically..

Comment: Scripting is not programming ?  You can put your logic and write a shell script. I am not clear what you mean by programatically

Comment: programatically means,a java method should be able to pickup all the suites and iterate them for a specified number of times

Comment: Then write a java class and in there you can execute the same command which you are executing from CLI. Please check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464111/run-cmd-commands-through-java . You can put your own logic in the java class.