# Java move application to startup folder

Tags: java, move, startup, autostart

I am trying to add my APP to startup folder.

```
public class info {
    
    public static String getautostart() {
        return System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir").replace("Local\\Temp\\", "Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup");
    }
    
    public static String gettemp() {
        String property = "java.io.tmpdir";
        String tempDir = System.getProperty(property);
        return tempDir;
    }
    
    public static String getrunningdir() {
        String runningdir = ProjectGav.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        return runningdir;
    }
    
}
```

That's the class I store info methods

And the main class:

```
    System.out.println(info.getautostart() + "\\asdf.jar");
    System.out.println(info.getrunningdir());
    Files.move(info.getrunningdir(), info.getautostart() + "\\asdf.jar");
```

This is the output from println:

> C:\Users\JOHNDO~1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\asdf.jar
>
> /C:/Users/John%20Doe/Downloads/project1.jar

The `files.move` is not working.

Comment: If I am not mistaken you need to create a shortcut in the windows startup folder, not copy the whole jar. Maybe [this script](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2008/12/03/how-to-create-shortcuts-in-windows-from-the-command-line/) can help you. My first idea would be: create a `.vbs` file (with the script from the link) next to your `.jar` file. And then [run the script via cmd](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15464449/896249) from your java application.

Comment: I want to move the file, not create a shortcut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK lets say you want to move your jar from the current directory to the autostart folder. You already have these methods:

```
// nothing to change here - it seems to work just fine
public static String getautostart() {
    return System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir").replace("Local\\Temp\\", "Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup");
}

// this one got confused with the '/' and '\' so I changed it
public static String getrunningdir() {
     //you need to import java.nio.file.Paths for that.
    String runningdir = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString(); // it simulates the creation of a file in the current directory and returns the path for that file
    return runningdir;
}
```

Now moving a file needs `Paths` and not `String` so you need to create a Path instance for each of your Strings:

```
 Path autostartPath = Paths.get(getautostart());
 Path currentPath = Paths.get(getrunningdir());
```

If you want to point to a file (like your `.jar` file) within the paths you can do this:

```
currentPath.resolve("myProgram.jar"); // The paths end with a `/` so you don't need to add it here
```

All together the `move`  should look like this:

```
Files.move(currentPath.resolve("myProgram.jar"), autostartPath.resolve("myProgram.jar"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `File` and `Path` objects instead of `String` objects (`Path` in `Files.move()`).

`Path` is made for adding 'parts' and you can check directory existence easily.

BTW, is the file you're moving, `asdf.jar`, also the file you're running? The JVM prevents running jars from being deleted or moved.

Comment: good point! Maybe `Files.copy(from, to)` would be a wiser choice here