# Using CLI in Java to manage Services

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I would like to run the `net start` and `net stop` command from java and fetch the results in java to administrate my services from there.
But I have no idea how to do that. Any Examples or Tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can check below links. It may help you in executing the cmd commands from Java code.

1. http://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/execute-operating-system-commands-using-runtime-exec-methods
2. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/
3. [Run cmd commands through java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464111/run-cmd-commands-through-java)