# How to write on a terminal using java programming

Tags: java, swing, debugging, ide, sdcc

I am using SDCC to design a compiler IDE (Using SDCC we can compile codes for 8051 and PIC controller).
To compile a a code written for 8051 we use the command `sdcc --debug filename.c` and to enter the debugger we use the command `sdcdb filename.cdb`. A Breakpoint can be set only in the debugger.
In a command prompt I can set the breakpoints using `break <linenumber>` but how can I implement this using the IDE?
When I'm using the IDE I don't want to set breakpoints by typing commands but I want to implement this function in a button. I have designed the IDE using Java Swing.

Comment: I don't really understand. You know of `System.out.print("string")`, right? Can you explain your question better?

Comment: Following may help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464111/run-cmd-commands-through-java]

Comment: I have gone through these but i don't want the terminal to close once it has executed some command. I want the terminal to be open and I have add few more commands @Kedar1442

Comment: You've said you want to write on a command prompt, but you also say it's for an IDE. Are you trying to write a debugger? You can use a `while` loop to capture key presses, but how will the program be exited? You also say you are trying to set breakpoints in an IDE, I asume from a prompt - you need to give thought about how to send the info to the IDE> What's wrong with just using the IDE to set breakpoints directly? What are you *really* trying to do?