# want to "open cmd" amd "run command" in java

Tags: java, node.js, cmd

I know I can open cmd with this code

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","start"});
```

but i want to create JButton for open cmd ,run command and show result in cmd screen(not console java) together.

ex. open cmd and run command "java -v" for check java version or "npm install"

my code

```
btnChkVersion.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //I DONT KNOW :(
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm afraid we don't know either, what don't you know?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464111/run-cmd-commands-through-java?rq=1

Comment: So what happens when you use the first code snippet inside the second one?

Comment: @UnholySheep it show cmd screen only one but i want to run command(ex. java -v) together

Comment: And if you adapt the array to be `{"cmd.exe","/c","start","java","-v"}` you don't get that result? I'm still unsure what exactly the problem is (or what the exact result is supposed to look like)

Comment: Why not just query the java version inside the runtime?

Comment: @UnholySheep {"cmd.exe","/c","start","java","-v"} it work! but cmd screen is auto close.