# How to run command line that run java app from java code?

Tags: java, linux, spring, macos

I have the following code:

```
private static String[] createCommandLinux(String cvPath, String jsonPath, String libPath) {

        List<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
        command.add("java");
        command.add("-cp");
        command.add("'" + libPath + "/ResumeTransducer/bin/*:" +
                libPath + "/GATEFiles/lib/*:" +
                libPath + "/GATEFiles/bin/gate.jar:" +
                libPath + "/ResumeTransducer/lib/*'");
        command.add("code4goal.antony.resumeparser.ResumeParserProgram");
        command.add("'" + cvPath + "'");
        command.add("'" + jsonPath + "'");

        String[] commandArr = new String[command.size()];
        commandArr = command.toArray(commandArr);
        return commandArr;
    }

...
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(createCommandLinux(cvPath,jsonPath,libPath));
...
```

I copy the command to run on MACOS terminal and it works fine. But when run this command within java application, it can not work as terminal does. It notifies that it can not find the main class. Do you know what the issue with it on MAXOS ?

Thanks

Comment: Is that your full java code?

Comment: Did you declare your main class which contains the public static void main(String[] args) method public? or is it just class <ClassName>{...} ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run cmd commands through java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464111/run-cmd-commands-through-java) with the command as `javac filenamehere.java`

Comment: Don't add single quotes around the names. They are used by the shell, and you are now replacing the shell.

Comment: Have you looked at ProcessBuilder?https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: I think there is no problem with single quote because it works on terminal