# org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error with ChromeDriver Chrome Selenium and TestNG Suite

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I am observing below error when I am executing TestNG suite through TestNG XML.

> SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with
>   an 
>       error: -1073741502 (Exit value: -1073741502)
>       FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod initializetest
>       org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
>       Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
>       System info: host: 'PDC2LAP-7173253', ip: '10.170.10.178', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_162'
>       Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:168)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>         at testclasses.BaseClass.initializetest(BaseClass.java:25)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:585)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)
>         at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>       Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:33768/status] to be available
>   after 20001 ms
>         at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
>         ... 35 more
>       Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
>         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
>         ... 36 more

The tests run smoothly initially for 10-12 tests but fails later with the above error message. I am hoping this is some issue with the configuration versions but I am not able to find it out.

Project has below POM :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>PageObjects</groupId>
  <artifactId>CustomerPortal</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>CustomerPortal</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>2.41.2</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.9.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Java Version is java version "1.8.0_201". ChromeDriver 2.43.600210. Please help me with this issue as the tests are failing abruptly leaving the whole Automation Script unstable.

TestNG is organized as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="CustomerPortalTestSuite-SIT2">
  <test thread-count="5" name="CustomerPortalTestExecution">
    <classes>
    <class name="testclasses.CustomerPortalSupportTest"/>
    <class name="testclasses.CustomerPortalAccountTest"/>
    <class name="testclasses.CustomerPortalBillingTest"/>
    <class name="testclasses.CustomerPortalHomeTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Below is the code written in @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod,

```
@BeforeMethod
public void initializetest() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Downloads\\ChromeDriverLatest\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver =new ChromeDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void endTest() throws IOException, Exception {
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\SeleniumScreenshots\\" + count +".jpg"));
            count++;
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
        driver=null;
    }
```

Test Class Sample Below :

```
@DataProvider(name="editAccDetails")
    public Object[][] logincreds(){
        Object[][] data = new Object[1][2];
        data[0][0] = "test";
        data[0][1] = "test";
        return data;
    }


    @Test(priority=1, dataProvider="editAccDetails")
    public void Details(String UsernameDP, String PasswordDP) throws Exception {
            Login TS1 = new Login(driver,wait);
            TS1.test(UsernameDP, PasswordDP);
            HomePage TS2 = new HomePage(driver,wait);
            TS2.test();
            AccountPages TS3 = new AccountPages(driver,wait);
            TS3.Details();

    }
```

Comment: Share your complete Java test class

Comment: Added above @waqar

Comment: What is at line no 25 in BaseClass.java?

Comment: driver=new ChromeDriver(); is at line 25 in my code. @waqar

Comment: Please add complete code of classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@kovid, hi. 
Lets try to debug it in a step by step way:

- 1) update [selenium server](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) to latest one version
- 2) ensure that You use [latest chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/) as well

Could You please also share `testng.XML` suite how its organized and share test code You're attempting to execute please?

From the exception I see -  its trying to reach browser instance and for some reason its non accessible. 
Might be called
`driver.close();`
or
`driver.quit();` Somewhere in the code.

And regarding testNG configuration -  You may take a look in [framework specs](https://testng.org/doc/index.html)  and/or  [example](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/TA/TestNG)  representing how test suite is organized.

Hope it be helpful for You,
regards,
Eugene

==============
**UPD 2019/03/02**
In addition to the explicit versioning @debanjanB provided above ^^ , I'd recommend to re-work code  a bit in the following way:

**IMPROVEMENT #1**
Driver init (I've separated this method with appropriate configs ; personally I'm using selenium GRID , but You may keep using Chromedriver You use in your code, I'd say its a matter of habbit):

```
public static WebDriver driverSetUp(WebDriver driver) throws MalformedURLException {

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("-incognito");
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capability.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
//System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.home")+"/Documents/:Proj_folder:/chromedriver");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
capability.setCapability("nativeEvents", true);
LoggingPreferences logs = new LoggingPreferences();
//Javascript console logs from the browser
logs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.WARNING);
logs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs);
String webDriverURL = "http://" + environmentData.getHubIP() + ":" + environmentData.getHubPort() + "/wd/hub";
log.info("creating driver instance on the URL :#### " + webDriverURL);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(webDriverURL), capability);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
return driver;}





public static WebDriver driverInit(WebDriver driver, String startingUrl) throws MalformedURLException {
    driver = DriverInit.driverSetUp(driver);
    driver.get(startingUrl);

    return driver;
}
```

And if You need to do driver-restart action -  You may use driver init with `driver.close()`  wrapped in try-catch block

```
public static WebDriver driverRestart(WebDriver driver, String startingUrl) throws MalformedURLException {
    try {
        driver.close();
    } catch (WebDriverException e) {
        log.error("#### oops, seems driver instance have been already closed. Doing re-initialization right now!", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return driverInit(driver, startingUrl);
}
```

So **AfterMethod** will look  like(Please add  **'alwaysRun=true'** flag):

```
   @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void closeDriverInstance() {
        try {
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(
String.format("c:\\SeleniumScreenshots\\%s.jpg", count)));
            driver.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(" oops, it seems that driver instance have been already closed.");
        }
    }
```

**IMPROVEMENT #2**

Please modify testng XML a bit (please add **parallel="false"** tag explicitly in suite tag):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="CustomerPortalTestSuite-SIT2" parallel="false" thread-count="5" verbose="8">
  <test name="CustomerPortalTestExecution">
    <classes>
    <class name="testclasses.CustomerPortalSupportTest"/>
    <class name="testclasses.CustomerPortalAccountTest"/>
    <class name="testclasses.CustomerPortalBillingTest"/>
    <class name="testclasses.CustomerPortalHomeTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**IMPROVEMENT #3** (assumption)
if that not helps. From experience, if for some tests chrome instance is started and many times closed and re-launched again - You may still have bunch of 
*chromedriver.exe* processes (hanging in Your system and preventing new chromedriver processed to start)

[image: Chromedriver processes list]

So if You figure out that You have many processes,  to kill them in WIN -You may call the command:

```
Taskkill /T /F /IM chromedriver.exe
```

So considering that You 'kill' each time Your chrome after every test method, You may  additionally kill any chromedriver processes in after method as well (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15464449/1546574)   how to execute cmd wrapped in java code).

Hope that finally helps :) 
Regards,
Eugene

Comment: Thanks @eugene for your input. Selenium Server is the latest one along with the ChromeDriver. I have added the TestNG.XML structure above.

Comment: @KovidMehta, could You please also share what  methods/code do You call in `@BeforeSuite`
`@BeforeTest`
`@BeforeClass`
`@BeforeMethod`
and in after-methods please?

Comment: Added the code in BeforeMethod and AfterMethod above Eugene.

Comment: quick question  -  do You need to get tests running in parallel  or they should be executed in one-by-one mode?

Comment: Executed one by one would be my preference.

Comment: @KovidMehta, updated my answer, Please feel free to up-vote if it helps for You. Thankful in advance.

Comment: Thanks @eugene. This worked wonders. Just made changes to TestNG XML and AfterMethod and ran the suite. It worked perfectly and executed all the tests without any errors. Thank you so much for such detailed step by step explanation. Will try to implement the CMD part soon.

Comment: anytime @KovidMehta

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start. 
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' 
System info: host: 'PDC2LAP-7173253', ip: '10.170.10.178', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_162' 
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to interact with a *WebElement*.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

Though you mentioned about using:

- Java Version is java version "1.8.0_201"
- ChromeDriver 2.43.600210

Tracelogs says:

> **`java.version: '1.8.0_162'`**

As you are using *Selenium v3.141.59* the components are not compatible.

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u201**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.46**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v71-73*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.46 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt))

Comment: Thanks @debanjan for your inputs. Tried to update all the above but still saw that error. I was able to run the Suite after making changes in testng XML and After method.