# How to run CMD in Java

Tags: java, cmd

I`m new at Java and I need to run CMD or Powershell in  java because i want to find out the current RAM utilization and the current disk distribution
On StackOverflow are many similar questions but I don't get it.

Here is my code, I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464111/run-cmd-commands-through-java):

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public static class CmdTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                    "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\" && dir");
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process p = builder.start();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while (true) {
                line = r.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I only get an empty console and I don't know why.

Comment: Your ProcessBuilder arguments do not match with your actual question (atleast some parts of the argument).

Comment: I appreciate the accept ;-)

Comment: I realized that I wrote complete garbage at that time.
Thanks that you had so much patience at that timexD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

The **main** method of your **Main** class is empty, does nothing.

You then added another **inner** class of Main, named **CmdTest**. But that class, respectively its main gets never called.

My suggestion, simply go, remove the CmdTest class, and put its code into your existing Main.main():

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(...
```

You could also rename Main.java to CmdTest.java, and (basically) remove the old Main, and have your CmdTest be its own public top level class.

And just for the record: formatting matters big time. It took me 2 minutes to figure your problem. Why? Because of misleading formatting. If you had indented reasonably, the underlying problem would have been obvious in 5 seconds. Thus: always indent consistently, and put } on a new line, even when the block/method is empty!

Finally: given the self-answer by the OP with more syntax experiments, the real answer here: step back. Look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html) for example to understand how a correct class + main have to look like. **Understand** the details, then start inserting your own code.