# Run cmd commands in the background through java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, cmd, filechooser

I am creating a GUI in java that requires a set of commands to be run through the command line one after the other in the background after the user selects a file and clicks a button in the GUI. The commands to be executed will include the path of the file. How can I get the command line to run in the background with a set of commands after the user selects a button?

The GUI as of now only includes the file chooser.

```java
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class GUIProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
        int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        // int returnValue = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()); //Instead of printing send it to cmd and perform more commands 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the use of building a gui if you are going to work through a terminal?

Comment: [Run cmd commands through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464111/run-cmd-commands-through-java)

Comment: Have a look at SwingWorker to integrate background tasks with a swing GUI.

Comment: @Stultuske Perhaps an application to "hide" the terminal behind a presumably more user-friendly GUI?

Comment: @Slaw yes, but then the terminal usage wouldn't be there anymore

Comment: @Stultuske But I believe that's the point. To let the user choose a file via a GUI and then fork a CMD process to execute the needed series of actions.

Comment: I would advice to use [**`ProcessBuilder`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String command = "cd C:\users";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

And for multiple commands you can use the `&&` operator

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"start somefile.bat && start other.bat && cd C:\\test && test.exe\"");
```

Comment: (command) is where I add my command?

Comment: What about multiple commands?

Comment: @abc see the edited answer

Comment: hey, I seem to get this error -  The system cannot find the file specified