# Running Espresso test inside APK

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, automated-tests, android-espresso

I want to run an Espresso test suit inside APK.

Here is how I have tried

```
runTest("am instrument -w -m -e debug false -e class 'com.demo.ic.BrightnessTest' com.demo.ic.athens.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner")

public String runTest(String command) {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            int read;
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.append(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            reader.close();
            // Waits for the command to finish.
            process.waitFor();
            return output.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Getting below error

TestLoader: Could not find class: 'com.demo.ic.BrightnessTest'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Invalid name: 'com.demo.ic.BrightnessTest'

Do I need to define anything to include test case into apk or any other way to do?

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to achieve, but all the espresso tests gets bundled into `androidTest.apk`, and your release apk doesn't contain any test classes.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't include your test classes inside your debug/release apk.**

All the android tests classes are bundled into a separate `androidTest.apk` which you can generate using a simple gradle command:

```
./gradlew assembleVARIANT_NAMEAndroidTest
```

Make sure to replace `VARIANT_NAME` with the specific build variant in your project. If you don't specify a variant name, gradle will look through all the module and will build apk for each variant.
The `apk` generated using above will be located inside `app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/` directory of your project.

If you simply want to run the tests, you can use this command:

```
./gradlew connectedVARIANT_NAMEAndroidTest
```

Here also, you'll need to specify the target variant otherwise it'll run tests for each variant.

Comment: Thanks, Shivam, The solution which I am looking for currently is to run test suit directly from apk not connecting the device with android studio and running ADB shell cmd. I hope you are getting my point because I have both apk in the device App under test and Test APK.

Comment: You can't run the `adb shell` shell command from inside of your app. That simply won't work since your app has no knowledge of androidTest apk. And I'm not sure if android will let you run `adb` commands in your app. `adb` is a command line tool which isn't supposed to run from the device.

Comment: Thank Shivam for the update. Anyway I found the similar solution here which I am looking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339216/how-to-start-instrumentation-project-programmatically-using-android-intent