# Connect android device to computer with usb and send data(string,int)

Tags: android, android-usb

System is like that, android device is pluged to macintosh with usb cable.

And in my android application, i want to send data (a line of string,int, it does not matter) to my computer.

How can i do that ? Is it possible ?

Do i need an application on computer for that ? Or is terminal enough?

Answer (score -1):

I would create an `IRC bitlbee server` on my computer, then send the string, or whatever through an `IRC channel` in it.

Or maybe you could find an app that does it.

Comment: any example for this ?

Comment: see this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388250/how-to-send-string-from-android-to-pc-over-wifi

Comment: this is about wifi, not usb