# How to connect program in PC to Application in Android Device

Tags: android, window

I have an App(A) in Android device and a C++ program(B)  in PC. I want to connect A to B to share datas from A to B. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Via some kind of Internet service

Comment: I want to share via USB cable.

Comment: you can use ADB to read-write data (files?) to-from Android device

Comment: thank @Vlad Matvienko, but i have files in folder app, i want to share these files to  my App in Window only .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you want to transfer data from Andriod to PC application. If you want this then you can do it using socket. You can send or receive data using socket communication between Andriod and PC devices or some other device.

One of such example you can found in below links

[how to Send string from Android to PC over wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388250/how-to-send-string-from-android-to-pc-over-wifi)

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sending-and-Receiving-Data-with-Sockets

Comment: Oh, thank you, the thing i want is the program in PC can access private data of Aplication in Android.