# How to send data from PC (INTRANET connection) to an app?

Tags: android

can somebody give me an idea of how to send some notifications from a PC with only INTRANET connection to a android app ? In this moment I am available only to send e-mail from this PC to a external gmail address ( via domino server ) but I want to go on next level and to send some notification from that PC to a android app on my phone. My idea is to send an e-mail from PC ( domino server ) to a external gmail address and some how from that gmail address to a android app. ( I do not want to use different mail app, I do not want to see notifications like an email ).

Thanks a lot guys for help and involvement !!!

Comment: You will want to look into local ethernet options via the ADB. See this link here for how to connect, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/2480714, and from there you can develop a more refined way to make custom notifications of your choosing (IE, running an app that listens on localhost ports / endpoints)

Answer (score 0):

So one way to do this is to setup an websocket or webserver and then communicate between the PC and the device. I've helped a client with such an implementation. The library we used was [nanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd). But searching google quickly find other possible road to take like [how to Send string from Android to PC over wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388250/how-to-send-string-from-android-to-pc-over-wifi).